# When does std::map call the constructor for the mapped type?

Tags: c++, c++03

If I have a container like this....

```
std::map <std::string, IHaveAReallyExpensiveConstructor_t>
```

Am I guaranteed that the constructor `IHaveAReallyExpensiveConstructor_t()` will only be called whenever I create a new element in the map, say with `std::map::operator[]`?

If it matters, only default construction is hard.  Copy construction is cheap and not really a concern.

Comment: A simple test shows that to be true, although you can avoid any default construction with the `emplace` member function and the `count` member function.

Comment: @QuestionC the fast way to find out is to start the debugger and put a breakpoint in the expensive constructor , see if that will get called. Also the default constructor should be called when you do `value = my_map[key]` when key is not in the map

Comment: The real question is whether the standard specifies a maximum number of calls to the constructor. I'm not sure it does. Failing that, measuring your current library implementation is the best you can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, `operator[]` is the only operation on `std::map` which requires `mapped_value` to be default constructible; so that is the only operation which could default-construct a value. `emplace` will also default-construct a value if you don't provide any constructor arguments.

If your implementation doesn't conform with C++11, then there's no guarantee that other operations won't construct a value; but no reason why any sane implementation would.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 cases for this:-

my_map[key] = value

1) If key is not in the map then copy constructor of "value" would be called to make a copy of that object in map.

2) If key is already present in the map, then there will be call to assignment operator of that object.

Comment: No, if the key isn't present then this would default-construct a new value, then copy-assign that from `value`. There's no way for `operator[]` to know that its return value will be used for assignment.